# Javascript optimize browser reflow

Tags: javascript

I want optimize updates the styles through javascript and avoiding browser reflow.

Check if the style is already setted seem to improve performance

```
if( element.style.width !== '100px' ) {
   element.style.width = '100px';
}
```

instead of direct update (without check)

```
element.style.width = '100px';
```

this is the benchmark: https://jsben.ch/Os8ik

Is a best practice check if the style is already setted for optimize browser reflow?

SIDE NOTE: the same it's not true for add class https://jsben.ch/vsyRJ

Comment: Is there a reason why you think you have to "optimize" something? How did you verify that?

Comment: Your approach will only work, if all your styles are set in the markup with the `style="..."` attribute which is a terrible idea.

Comment: If you reassign a `style` property to the exact same value and this causes a reflow in the browser, that is a bug in the engine. There's nothing you need to optimise in javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is a best practice check if the style is already setted for optimize browser reflow?

No, this is not a best practice. The browser itself does that and will *not* cause a reflow if the value doesn't change.

<sup>(That said, as far as I can remember there was a bug with this in some old safari version, so some developers that were affected by this actually had to add such a workaround in their code. Iirc it was only a specific property, though.)</sup>

Comment: Why in the benchmark https://jsben.ch/Os8ik win check before set?

Comment: @SimoneNigro Because a read is less costly than a write, it's just a different method call in the DOM API. The difference is minuscule. If  the browser was actually performing a reflow in there, the numbers would be off by multiple magnitudes.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to optimize are element dependencies in regards to positioning.

Consider the following:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="absolute_child"></div>
    <div id="floating_child"></div>
    <div id="another_floating_child"></div>
</div>
```

and CSS

```
.container .div{width:100px; height:100px; display:block; position:relative;}
#absolute_child {position:absolute;}
#floating_child, #another_floating_child  {float:left;}
```

Here, if you change size or position of #absolute_child, reflow does not happen because no other elements are calculated in relation to it. However, if you mess around with floating elements, each is calculated in relation to another, causing expensive reflows.

There are nuances of this, but if you want to dynamically change the elements, take them out from the [normal flow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Normal_Flow) to optimize the performance.